# MATLAB: Insert a string into a string

Tags: string, matlab

Is there a clever (simple) way to insert a string into another string?  My gut tells me this is an old problem solved many ways.

For example, insert 'cats' into the string:

'It's raining and dogs today.'

to yield:

'It's raining cats and dogs today.'

In my m-file, I use:

```
tempString='cats ';
gpsFile='It's raining and dogs today.';
pFlights=14;  % insertion point of target string
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for when you say "clever" or "simple." What are you doing now, for comparison?

Comment: Ideally there would be a function to use the 3 variables I have described to create a larger string, split the target string and copy the 3 strings into the larger string to be returned, though I am hoping that there is a better algorithm or this has been already solved (missed the .m file that does this).

Answer (score 1):

Let us set two strings named `s0`, `s1`. We insert `s1` to `s0` at position `p` in `s0`.
The code is simple:

```
strcat( strcat( s0(1:p-1), s1 ), s0(p:end) )
```

Or a better solution from the comment of [O'Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3893262/oneil):

```
[s0(1:p-1), s1, s0(p:end)]
```

Comment: Or simpler using brackets: `[s0(1:p-1), s1, s0(p:end)]`

Comment: @O'Neil Yes, great!

Comment: @O'Neil: this should be promoted to answer! :)

Comment: @gatorback Essentially they are exactly the same, just different expressions. ;)

Comment: @Daniel Also note that [strcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) can accept more than 2 inputs: `strcat(s0(1:p-1), s1, s0(p:end))`

Comment: @O'Neil I think that you comments are more valuable. ;)

Comment: And two additional facts why you should use the matrix concatenation: 1) srcat is much more slower 2) because it removes trailing white-spaces. So, if the original string contains white spaces, and you insert the new string on an index, where the last character of the first element is a white-space, you will lost that character.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in 16b there is insertBefore/insertAfter.

```
>> insertBefore('It''s raining and dogs today.', 14, 'cats ')

ans =

  1×33 char array

    'It's raining cats and dogs today.'
```

Performance comparison

```
function profFunc()

   chr = 'It''s raining and dogs today.';

   tic;
   for i = 1:1E5
       x = insertBefore(chr, 14, 'cats ');
   end
   toc

   str = string(chr);

   tic;
   for i = 1:1E5
       x = insertBefore(str, 14, 'cats ');
   end
   toc

   tic;
   for i = 1:1E5
       x = insertString('cats ',chr,14);
   end
   toc
end

function [ outString ] = insertString( s1, s0, p )
   outString=[s0(1:p-1), s1, s0(p:end)];
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 0.737172 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.245999 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.283983 seconds.
```

To summarize, insertBefore with char is slower than char indexing. insertBefore with string is a smidge faster than char indexing.

I've seen that if you can stay with an all string workflow you can see more performance improvements.

Comment: 16b is unavailable to me.  Wondering if insertBefore() has speed or other advantag over the function below: insertString().

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does 14 come from? strfind? regexp? Or a magic number that you already know ahead of time?

Comment: In my work, the '14' is calculated before  the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [ outString ] = insertString( s1, s0, p )
%insertString Insert s1 into s0 at point p
% 
outString=[s0(1:p-1), s1, s0(p:end)];
end
```

Hopefully, I have not re-invented the wheel